# How can I find fs_base in gdb?

Tags: gdb, leakcanary

I'm studying about master canary these days and I want to know where exactly `fs:0x28` is.

Is there any way to access to `fs_base` instead of using `$fs_base` command? (My gdb is outdated so I can't use the command.)

I tried to disassemble `security_init` function where the master canary is made, but I couldn't.